# Can't drag & drop SXA components in overlay content (through experience editor)

Tags: sxa, experience-editor, richtext-editor, links

I'm trying to edit an overlay content component in the Experience Editor but i just realized that i can't use SXA components such as Rich Text, Links etc (The drag & drop works but once it's dropped, nothing is displayed in the placeholder).

I don't have this problem with components i've created myself and added to the toolbox.

If anyone can put some light on that problem.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: What is your SXA version, 1.5?

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak : Yes, v1.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue in **SXA 1.5**, it was fixed in **SXA 1.6** so if you can I highly recommend you to upgrade.

Rendering Variants do not work on Overlay items thus you cannot see renderings because they have no default rendering variant selected.

You can still assign RV in Raw Values but I think this is not a solution

## Quick fix:

### Custom service

Add missing **Overlay** template and it will be fine. In **1.6** this collection was extracted into a configuration so it is much easier to add additional templates that do not inherit from any of the existing base templates (Page, Overlay, Partials...)

```csharp
namespace Alan.Services
{
    public class AvailableRenderingVariantService : Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Services.AvailableRenderingVariantService
    {
        public AvailableRenderingVariantService()
        {
            AllowedTemplates = new List<ID>(AllowedTemplates) { Templates.OverlayContent.ID }.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

### Custom service - registration

```csharp
namespace Alan
{
    public class RegisterVariantsAbstractionsServices : IServicesConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IVariantFieldParser, VariantFieldParser>();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ITemplateRenderer, TemplateRenderer>();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IVariantRenderer, VariantRenderer>();
            // HERE YOU REGISTER YOUR CUSTOM SERVICE
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IAvailableRenderingVariantService, Services.AvailableRenderingVariantService>(); 
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IVariantRenderingService, VariantRenderingService>();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IRulesService, RulesService>();
        }
    }
}
```

### Configuration

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <services>
    <configurator patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.IoC.RegisterVariantsAbstractionsServices, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions']" type="Alan.Services.RegisterVariantsAbstractionsServices, Alan" />
    </services>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

> **Once you update to 1.6 you have to remove this fix.**